# Getting error while running selenium code

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am getting below error while running selenium code while everything is right in code. Please help

Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element .//*[@id='content']/p[2] not found
    at     com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:272)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.getText(DefaultSelenium.java:471)
    at selrcdemo.RCDemo.main(RCDemo.java:35)

```
package selrcdemo;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
public class RCDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444 , "firefox",  "http://www.calculator.net");
    selenium.start();   // Start
    selenium.open("/");  // Open the URL
    selenium.windowMaximize();

    // Click on Link Math Calculator
    selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='menu']/div[3]/a");
    Thread.sleep(2500); // Wait for page load

    // Click on Link Percent Calculator
    selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='menu']/div[4]/div[3]/a");
    Thread.sleep(4000); // Wait for page load


    // Focus on text Box
    selenium.focus("name=cpar1");
    // enter a value in Text box 1
    selenium.type("css=input[name=\"cpar1\"]", "10");

    // enter a value in Text box 2
    selenium.focus("name=cpar2");
    selenium.type("css=input[name=\"cpar2\"]", "50");

    // Click Calculate button
    selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    // verify if the result is 5
    String result = selenium.getText(".//*[@id='content']/p[2]");


    if (result == "5")
    {
        System.out.println("Pass");
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Fail");
    }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open this site, you'll find that the output is not getting stored in the third text box, rather it is getting displayed above, just under where "Result" is written.

You'll have to make some changes in the code(the xpath for click button and that for the third text box, i.e. from where the value is getting picked). The following codes works perfectly:

```
    package seleniumrcdemo;

    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class rcdemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

  // Instatiate the RC Server
  Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444 , "firefox", "http://www.calculator.net");
  selenium.start();   // Start
  selenium.open("/");  // Open the URL
  selenium.windowMaximize();

  // Click on Link Math Calculator
  selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='menu']/div[3]/a");
  Thread.sleep(2500); // Wait for page load

  // Click on Link Percent Calculator
  selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='menu']/div[4]/div[3]/a");
  Thread.sleep(4000); // Wait for page load

  // Focus on text Box
  selenium.focus("name=cpar1");
  // enter a value in Text box 1
  selenium.type("css=input[name=\"cpar1\"]", "10");

  // enter a value in Text box 2
  selenium.focus("name=cpar2");
  selenium.type("css=input[name=\"cpar2\"]", "50");

  // Click Calculate button
  selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[2]");

  // verify if the result is 5
  Thread.sleep(4000);
  String result = selenium.getText("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/p[2]/font/b");
  //String result = selenium.getValue("xpath=.//*[@id='cpar3']");
  System.out.println("result"+result);

  if (result.equals("5")/*== "5"*/){
     System.out.println("Pass");
  }
  else{
     System.out.println("Fail");
  }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to add xpath= inside your quotes. Or do:

```
String result = selenium.findElement(By.xpath('path')).getText();
```

Your answer (result) doesn't exist in the second p.  After closer inspect the xpath is:

```
/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/p[2]/span
```

Comment: After adding xpath = ".//*[@id='content']/p[2]" I am getting result as Fail

Comment: If you take your xpath and plug it into chrome inpect or firefox firebug does it return?

Answer (score 0):

The statement
String result = selenium.getText(".//*[@id='content']/p[2]");
missing the "xpath=".
The correct statement

```
String result = selenium.getText("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/p[2]");
```

But this will return the result "10% of 50 = 5", which of course != "5". The exact xpath is for the element "5" is "xpath=.//*[@id='content']/p[2]/span/font/b". So the statement should be

```
String result = selenium.getText("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/p[2]/span/font/b");
```

You'll still get "Fail" in comparing the String literals. Suggest to use equals() or compareTo() method when comparing strings:

```
    if (result.equals("5"))
    {
        System.out.println("Pass");
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Fail");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    // verify if the result is 5
    String result = selenium.getText("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/p[2]/span/font/b");

    if (result.equals("5")){
        System.out.println("Pass");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Fail");
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score -1):

correct me if I am wrong

the % calculation module  in  calculator web application is failed to pass test case, may be the application code requires a bug fix , the result is not displaying on the rhs(cpar3) side

```
xpath=.//*[@id='cpar3']==>RHS xpath
```

here is the selenium code which works fine for me if i manually enter the result value to 5

```
package selRcDemo;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class RcDemo {
    /**
     * @param args
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Instatiate the RC Server
        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "firefox",
                "http://www.calculator.net");
        selenium.start(); // Start
        selenium.open("/"); // Open the URL
        selenium.windowMaximize();

        // Click on Link Math Calculator
        selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='menu']/div[3]/a");
        Thread.sleep(2500); // Wait for page load

        // Click on Link Percent Calculator
        selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='menu']/div[4]/div[3]/a");
        Thread.sleep(4000); // Wait for page load

        // Focus on text Box
        selenium.focus("name=cpar1");
        // enter a value in Text box 1
        selenium.type("css=input[name=\"cpar1\"]", "10");

        // enter a value in Text box 2
        selenium.focus("name=cpar2");
        selenium.type("css=input[name=\"cpar2\"]", "50");

        // Click Calculate button
        selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='content']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[2]");
        Thread.sleep(2500);

        // verify if the result is 5
        String result = selenium.getText("xpath=.//*[@id='cpar3']");
        // result="5";
        System.out.println(result);
        // result is not equal to 5 due to bug in application code its returning
        // "" (no value)
        if (result.equals("5")) {
            System.out.println("Pass");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }

}
```